# JQuery hide/show property is not working in my code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have written code to upload multiple files by cloning input field in jquery.

Here the logic is; if `#file_1` field is empty, the `$('#addBtn').on('click', function ()` is supposed to go in `else` part of if condition and display the relevant hidden `<p>` tag. If first field is left empty, the add button (add more button) should not clone the field. Instead it should show a message to user to upload file in the first available field first and the click add button to upload more file. Here Jquery `show()/hide` function is not working.
Please have a look on my code, I'll be much obliged. Thank you!

```js
console.log('objection page here');
var Index = 1;
// START CODE FOR BASIC DATA TABLE
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#addBtn').on('click', function () {
        var uploadFieldVal = $('#file_'+ Index).val();
        console.log(uploadFieldVal);
        
        if(uploadFieldVal !="")
        {
             Index++;
            var uFile = $('#file_1').clone();
            //var id = "btnAdd_" + Index;
              var fileItem = "<input type='file' name='fileUpload[file][]'' id='file_" + Index +  "'class='form-control'/> ; " + 
        "<p id='fileMsg_" + Index + "style='visibility: hidden; color: red'>Please attach file here first </p>;"
        $('#fileDiv').append(fileItem);
          

        }
        else
        {
              
              console.log('fileMsg_'+Index);
              $('#fileMsg_'+Index).show();
              
              //$('#fileMsg_1).show(); //its also not working
        }
       
 });
});
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary float-right" id="addBtn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="form-group" id="fileDiv">
                    <label for="file_1">File</label>
                <input type="file"  name="fileUpload[file][]" id="file_1" class="form-control"/>
               <p id="fileMsg_1" style="visibility: hidden; color: red">Please attach file here first </p>
               </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "not working." Does it do anything? Does it throw an error?

Comment: no it does not throw any error.I have hidden the <p> initially. when user clicks add(+) button without uploading any file in first field, jquery is supposed to unhide <p> in else part

Comment: Why are you incermenting your Index? `Index++;` This would turn your `1` into a `2` and this, `'fileMsg_'+Index` would equate to `'fileMsg_2'` which does not exist. You should see this in your Console.

Comment: @Twisty please look in the console for ''fileMsg_'+Index' value in else part. Index does not increment in else part and remains 1.

Comment: @Twisty for the clarification I have added ``$('#fileMsg_1).show();`` to assure the  jquery``show()`` function for the exact id of``<p>`` tag is now showing / unhiding the hidden ``<p>`` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.show()` does not work on CSS for visibility.

> The matched elements will be revealed immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling `.css( "display", "block" )`, except that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially. If an element has a display value of `inline`, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

```js
$(function() {
  console.log('objection page here');
  var Index = 1;
  $('#addBtn').on('click', function() {
    var uploadFieldVal = $('#file_' + Index).val();
    console.log(uploadFieldVal);
    if (uploadFieldVal != "") {
      Index++;
      var uFile = $('#file_1').clone();
      var fileItem = "<input type='file' name='fileUpload[file][]'' id='file_" + Index + "' class='form-control'/> ; ";
      fileItem += "<p id='fileMsg_" + Index + "' style='visibility: hidden; color: red'>Please attach file here first </p>;"
      $('#fileDiv').append(fileItem);
    } else {
      console.log('fileMsg_' + Index);
      $('#fileMsg_' + Index).css("visibility", "visible");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary float-right" id="addBtn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
<div class="form-group" id="fileDiv">
  <label for="file_1">File</label>
  <input type="file" name="fileUpload[file][]" id="file_1" class="form-control" />
  <p id="fileMsg_1" style="visibility: hidden; color: red">Please attach file here first </p>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

You need to change visibility to `visible` to "show" it.

See More: https://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: Thank you for the explanation . There is still a minor problem in my code, css is not being applied in the dynamic tag `"<p id='fileMsg_" + Index + "style='visibility: hidden; color: red'>Please attach file here first </p>;"`  in JS file.

Comment: @EmmyAyes You're missing a closing quote for the id attribute.  `...+ Index + "' style='...`